# Web worker function return response two times for a single call

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am using web worker in my application to execute some operations. Calling the web worker `function` from my js file only once with `parameter`. But its executing twice, first time with out `parameter` (parameter 'undefined'). And second time with `parameter`. What am I doing wrong?

**js File**

```
function f1(data) {
  console.log('function called');
  ww.postMessage({ action: 'name', data: { params: data } });
  ww.onmessage = function(event) {
    res = event.data;
    console.log(event.data);
  };
}
```

in web worker file

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  functionName = e.data.action;
  data = e.data.data;
  switch (functionName) {
    case 'name':
      var res = processData(data);
      self.postMessage(res);
      break;
  }
});

function processData(data) {
  if (data.params != undefined) {
    console.log('parameter', data);
    //some code to run
    //finally
    return res;
  }
}
```

The out put I am getting in console

```
function called 
undefined // from event.data
parameter data //actual data I passed
{} //event.data  result of the action
```

Why is the `parameter data` not consoled the first time.

Comment: could you update your question with your complete code ... I don't see the web workers `postMessage()` function in there

Comment: thanks for comment, postMessage() is inside the f1 function

Comment: What I meant is that you did not include the function definition of the `postMessage()` function

Comment: Didn't  get you. I think you want more detail about my f1 function, but this is the actual one I am using.

Comment: nevermind ... I forgot that you are using a web-worker which has the built in function `postMessage`

Comment: If the solution I provided in my answer works for you please accept it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some smaller errors in your code that prevents a smooth execution

**1. you forgot to declare `functionName` and `data` as variables**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var functionName = e.data.action;
  var data = e.data.data;
  switch (functionName) {
    case 'name':
      var res = processData(data);
      self.postMessage(res);
      break;
  }
});
```

**2. Your `return` value was never declared as variable as well**

```
function processData(data) {
  if (data.params !== undefined) {
    console.log('parameter', data);
    //some code to run
    //finally
    return data;
  }
}
```

**3. In your `callback` function you did not declare `res` as variable as well**

```
var ww = new Worker('worker.js');

function f1(data) {
  console.log('function called');
  ww.postMessage({ action: 'name', data: { params: data } });
  ww.onmessage = function(event) {
    var res = event.data;
    console.log(res);
  };
}

f1('test');
```

---

I strongly advise to use a sophisticated IDE such as PHPStorm or WebStorm which give hints on such smaller (and bigger) errors, because they reference the whole application and therefore know where something is called and defined.